# Is my phone's GPS limited by US regulations?

Tags: gps, samsung-droid-charge

Apparently any GPS module made in the US and exported is classified as a munition if it is:

> Capable of providing navigation information under the following operational condition:
>
> 1. At speeds in excess of 515 m/sec (1,000 nautical miles/hour);
> 2. At altitudes in excess of 18 km (60,000 feet).

<sup>http://www.armscontrol.org/documents/mtcr</sup>

**Would the GPS still be usable above 18 km or while travelling more than 515 m/sec?**

I have a Droid Charge.

Comment: Is this a real question?

Comment: Yes, it is a real question.

Comment: It may be a real question, but it's not on topic for this site. This isn't a problem on your Android device; it's a question of law.

Comment: @AlEverett I've rephrased the question. I think it's on topic now.

Comment: Er... How often do you move in such a manner?

Comment: This isn't a question of law, it's a question about the stats of a typical GPS receiver on android phones--with an *interesting* application in US law. I guess it's just interesting to me, and off-topic to everyone else.

Comment: @SaintWacko Why does that matter? I could strap my phone to an intercontinental ballistic missile. I could send it to a space station. I could give it to a pilot of an airplane that goes mock 3. Or is it not good enough to say, hay man, just wonderin...?

Comment: Oh, no, it's a perfectly fine question, I was just wondering myself :D

Comment: @SaintWacko A few people have sent android devices to space as payload on weather ballons. Those regualrly go higher than 18 km.

Comment: I don't see why would this be regarded as a question of law. It states that there's a law in the us and ask if this phone is limited by that.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik - Oh, that's true, hadn't thought about that. Hm, I wonder what they did for GPS, then. Unless they just didn't bother with GPS above 18km.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No it's not.

Commercial GPS receivers (like the one in your phone) only work below 18 km and below 515 m/sec. The rationale behind this is that this way they can't be used in ballistic missiles (yes, I'm serious.)

In order to circumvent this you'd need to flash a different firmware to your GPS chip, if you didn't do this you're safe. No current android device ships with munitions grade GPS receiver.

Comment: +1, but is there any documentation that allows us to follow up on this issue?

Comment: @Zuul Anything specific you're looking for? I've found that arms regulations are not the most documented things in the world  :)

Comment: Someone came up with these limits to the civilian world. Somewhere, there's a paper or an article about it that one can read to better understand the surroundings of this issue :) Ultimately, I'm trying to have your answer corroborated by "official" documentation :D *(I've already up-voted, that should suffice to tell you that your word is enough for me)*

Comment: @Zull, please my answer to the question http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/508/how-accurate-is-the-gps-in-my-mobile-phone/26945#26945.

Comment: @Narayanan Thank you for the follow up. ps: It's  **Zuul** :D

Comment: Terribly sorry @Zuul. :)